# PHP Login session and echoing username

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is on my login page everything works just fine but the problem here is when i successfully login the username doest show up at the main page.

```
include ('connect.php');

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):
    $usernameLog = $_POST['usernameLog'];
    $passwordLog = $_POST['passwordLog'];
    $valid = true;

     if($valid == TRUE){
    include('connect.php');

    $usernameLog = mysql_real_escape_string($usernameLog);
    $passwordLog = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($passwordLog));

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = '$usernameLog' AND passconf = '$passwordLog'");


    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){

        //if true then lets go to the logged in page
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['logat'] = "da";

        header('location: BlogWorld.php');
```

I am not sure what's going wrong. Please help

//codes sesssion for the main page ie when user is successfully logged in

```
include('connect.php');

// Start session
    session_start();


// Check if user is logged and existing session
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            include ("connect.php");

// Content for user logged
    echo "Welcome ".$username." :) - <a href='logout_Blog.php'>Logout</a>";
    } else {
// Redirecting to login page
    Header("Location: ./");
```

Comment: Where is the code that should be print in the "main page"?

Comment: include('connect.php');
 
 // Start session
  session_start();
  
    
 // Check if user is logged and existing session
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    include ("connect.php");
    
 // Content for user logged
  echo "Welcome ".$username." :) - <a href='logout_Blog.php'>Logout</a>";
  } else {
 // Redirecting to login page
  Header("Location: ./");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `session_start()` at the top of the pages where you are using `session`.

And store

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $usernameLog;
```

Then `echo $_SESSION['username'];`

Comment: Its working now. thanks a lot.

i forgot to go back to the login form and store the variable username in the session.

Also instead of just $_SESSION['username'].. i was echoing  and it was not buying into the structure of my code

Comment: Happy to help u... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with this code,

include ('connect.php');

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):
$usernameLog = $_POST['usernameLog'];
$passwordLog = $_POST['passwordLog'];
$valid = true;

if($valid == TRUE){
include('connect.php');

$usernameLog = mysql_real_escape_string($usernameLog);
$passwordLog = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($passwordLog));

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = usernameLog' AND      passconf = '$passwordLog'");

$result=mysql_fetch_row( $sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){

    //if true then lets go to the logged in page
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['username'] = $result[0]['username'];

    header('location: BlogWorld.php');
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row()` fetches a single row, `$result[0]` won't work